Userform behavior changes based on how excel file opened
Running file using Office 365.
Program has Userform with a ListBox. If I open the file using Excel recent history, everything works fine. If I open the file by double-clicking file name in folder where it resides, the code throws a runtime error 91 as soon as I try to do anything with the ListBox. When debugging, the debugger claims the ListBox equals Nothing, implying it wasn't instantiated. Has anyone ever come across this? If so, what is the fix?
Looked at trust settings, but that doesn't appear to cover the issue. Don't know what else to look at.
